# Correct Use of MFC and GDI+

Tags: bitmap, mfc, gdi+

I am trying to render two different bitmaps in a mdi view, there is a flag, if this flag is true I render one bitmap, if it false I render the second one.
My problem is that it works correctly only when I minimize and maximize the view so for example if the flag changes the first bitmap does not disappear and the second one does not appear, as soon as I minimize and maximize back the view, the correct bitmap is rendered.

There are two colormatrix one with alpha =0 and the other one with alpha=1

```
void MyAppView::OnDraw(CDC* /*pDC*/)
{
    MyAppViewDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;
    if(flag == true)
    {
        m_pImageRenderer->drawImage(this);
    }

    else
    {
        m_pImageRenderer->drawOtherImage(this);
    }

}


void Renderer::drawImage(CWnd* pWnd)
{

    int X = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN );
    int Y = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN );


        CClientDC dc(pWnd);
        Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(dc);

        imageVisibleAttributes->SetColorMatrix(m_pColorMatrixVisible);
        imageInvisibleAttributes->SetColorMatrix(m_pColorMatrixInvisible);
        graphics.DrawImage(m_pConnectionNotAvailable, Rect(0, 0, 140, 140), 0, 0, 140, 140, UnitPixel, imageInvisibleAttributes);
        graphics.DrawImage(m_pConnectionAvailable, Rect(0, 0, 140, 140), 0, 0, 140, 140, UnitPixel, imageVisibleAttributes);
}


void ImageHandler::drawOtherImage(CWnd* pWnd)
{

    CClientDC dc(pWnd);
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(dc);
    imageVisibleAttributes->SetColorMatrix(m_pColorMatrixVisible);
    imageInvisibleAttributes->SetColorMatrix(m_pColorMatrixInvisible);
    graphics.DrawImage(image, Rect(0, 0, 140, 140), 0, 0, 140, 140,     UnitPixel, imageInvisibleAttributes);
    graphics.DrawImage(image2, Rect(0, 0, 140, 140), 0, 0, 140, 140, UnitPixel, imageVisibleAttributes);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it's not working but the fact that `OnDraw` is passing you a `CDC` but you are ignoring it and getting another one inside `drawImage` may have something to do with it. I would suggest changing `drawImage` to accept an optional `CDC` and to use this in preference to creating a new one.

Comment: Are you just forgetting to repaint when the flag changes? Just call `InvalidateRect(NULL)` wherever the flag gets changed.

Comment: Thanks guys was the Invalidate :(